# Parsing input text and outputting to a file

Tags: c++, parsing, char

I am writing a small program to parse an input file of Sony Cell SPU instructions and outputs to a text the binary format of the instruction.

The basic idea is this:

input text format is instruction rt/ra/rb

```
a r3,r2,r1
ah r6,r5,r4
```

output text format is: opcode/rb/ra/rt

```
00011000000000000100000100000011
00011001000000010000001010000110
```

So basically, im parsing the command syntax (a, ah, etc...) and determining the opcode. This information also gives me the format of the instruction (the register formats). Once i know the registers being accessed, i convert those values into 7-bit values so (r3 = 0000011, etc..). Then, i write the 32-bit converted instruction to an output text.

Where i am getting stuck is on how to do the parsing of the instruction syntax.

In particular, what I had in mind was to read in each line of the input text file into a `char array` and check the low bits of the index and compare it to a string for each of my instructions, but i do not think this is a good method.

What is a good method to perform this type of parsing and comparison?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to avoid a chain of

```cpp
if(strcmp(array, "cmd1") == 0)
else if(strcmp(array, "cmd2") == 0)
//...
```

Then you could try something like this:

```cpp
switch(array[0])
{
case 'a':
    switch(array[1])
    {
        case ' ':
            // end of command!
            break;
        case 'a':
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            // unknown command
        break;
    }
    break;
case 'b':
    // analogously
    break;
default:
    // unknown command
    break;
}
```

Depending on the number of commands and their length, this can easily get unreadable, though...

Another approach: Using [::std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) (or ::std::tr1::unordered_map, if using older C++ standard). Map your strings to appropriate handler functions (pointers to) or (polymorphic!) classes, if more appropriate. Make sure to retrieve the handler via find (not the index operator[], as this would add a new element) and simply call it... This approach is interesting if you have a rather large instruction set.

Perhaps something like this:

```cpp
void a(char* cmd) {/*...*/}
void ah(char* cmd) {/*...*/}
/* ... */

typedef ::std::unordered_map<char const*, void(*)(char*)> Handlers
void main(int, char*[])
{
    Handlers handlers;
    handlers["a"] = &a;
    handlers["ah"] = &ah;
    /* open file */
    char array[128];
    char* arguments;
    /* for each line: */
    {
        /*
         *read into array;
         * you need to separate the command from the
         * parameters e. g. by setting the first space following
         * to 0 ('\0'), and setting arguments to the first
         * non-whitespace afterwards
         */      

        Handlers::iterator handler = handlers.find(array);
        if(handler == handlers.end())
        {
            // unknown command
        }
        else
        {
            (*handler)(arguments);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```